# Iterator with `&mut` items

Tags: iterator, rust, lifetime, ownership, associated-types

I want to create an iterator for iterating through records in a huge file.

```
for record in huge_file.iter() {
  println!("{}", record.read_field("name"));
}
```

Each record individually is too big to fit in memory, so the iterator can't return owned `Record` objects with everything loaded into memory.  The underlying storage does not support random access, so returning "slices"/"views" of the storage is also not an option.

Instead, I want the iterator to return elements that allow the consumer to read from the current "cursor position" in the file.  Superficially, the API would look like this:

```
impl Iterator for HugeFileIterator {
  fn next<'a>(&'a mut self) -> Option<&'a mut Record> {
    ...
  }
}

impl Record {
  fn read_field(name: &str) -> &str {
    ...
  }
}
```

With that signature of `next`, the `mut` borrow ensures that the consumer can't keep a reference to the "previous `Record`" when calling `next()` to get the "next `Record`."

However, I can't get that type signature for `next` to work the way I want it to.  The `Iterator` trait requires me to define an associated `Item` type, and I don't know how it should look:

```
impl Iterator for HugeFileIterator {
  type Item<'a> = &'a mut Record; // ← Obviously doesn't work

  fn next<'a>(&'a mut self) -> Option<Self::Item<'a>> {
    ...
  }
}
```

Is it possible to express this constraint in the Rust type system?  Or is there perhaps another completely different approach that I haven't thought about?

Comment: std::slice::IterMut is an example of an iterator that iterates over "mutable references to the values". Perhaps it can serve as an inspiration. https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/slice/struct.IterMut.html

Comment: @nielsle That looks interesting! Sadly, the `IterMut` holds a `&mut` for the *iterator*, while I want to hold a `&mut` for every *element* in the iterator.